# Dataframe fast way to search backward in columns while expanding

Tags: python, pandas, search, expand

This is my dataframe of prices

```
   stock1  stock2
0     2.3    10.1
1     1.9    11.2
2     3.5    10.5
3     2.8    10.8
4     3.1    10.3
5     2.7     9.8
6     3.3    10.2
```

And this is dataframe of price supports I want to obtain

```
   stock1  stock2
0     NaN     NaN
1     1.9    10.1
2     1.9    10.1
3     1.9    10.5
4     2.8    10.1
5     1.9     NaN
6     2.7     9.8
```

Let's focus on the first column of prices. The idea is to calculate down peaks in this way

```
    prices1 = prices['stock1']
    mask = (prices1.shift(1) > prices1) & (prices1.shift(-1) > prices1)
    supports1 = prices1.where(mask, NaN)
    supports1.iloc[0] = min(prices1[0],prices1[1])
    supports1 = supports1.shift(1).fillna(method='ffill')
```

and we obtain

```
   stock1
0  NaN
1  NaN
2  1.9
3  1.9
4  2.8
5  2.8
6  2.7
```

Another rule is that, for every price, support must be lower. This doesn't happen in row 5 because 2.8 > 2.7. To correct we have to look backward in this support column to find first occurrence lower than current price (if exists otherwise NaN). In this case right value is 1.9

I found 2 ways to solve the problem but I need to iterate and when dataframe increases it becomes incredibly slow. I'd like 10 times faster, hopefully 100 times.
This is my code

```
from pandas import DataFrame
from numpy import NaN
from numpy.random import uniform
from timeit import timeit

##rows = 5000
##cols = 10
##d={}
##for i in range(cols):
##    d['stock_{}'.format(i)] = 100*uniform(0.95,1.05,rows).cumprod()
##prices = DataFrame(d)

prices = DataFrame({'stock1':[2.3, 1.9, 3.5, 2.8, 3.1, 2.7, 3.3],\
                    'stock2':[10.1, 11.2, 10.5, 10.8, 10.3, 9.8, 10.2]})



#----------------------------------------------------------------
def calc_supports1(prices):
    supports = DataFrame().reindex_like(prices)
    for stock in prices:
        prices1 = prices[stock]
        mask = (prices1.shift(1) > prices1) & (prices1.shift(-1) > prices1)
        supports1 = prices1.where(mask, NaN)
        supports1.iloc[0] = min(prices1[0],prices1[1])
        supports1 = supports1.shift(1).fillna(method='ffill')

        sup = supports1.drop_duplicates()
        for i,v in prices1.loc[prices1 < supports1].iteritems():
            mask = (sup.index < i) & (sup < v)
            sup2 = sup.values[mask.values]
            supports1.at[i] = sup2[-1] if len(sup2) > 0 else NaN

        supports[stock] = supports1
    return supports

#----------------------------------------------------------------
def calc_supports2(prices):
    supports = DataFrame().reindex_like(prices)
    for stock in prices:
        prices1 = prices[stock]
        sup = [min(prices1[0],prices1[1])]
        supports1 = [NaN, sup[0]]

        for i in xrange(2,len(prices1)):
            while len(sup) > 0 and prices1[i] < sup[0]:
                sup.pop(0)

            if prices1[i-1]<prices1[i] and prices1[i-1]<prices1[i-2]:
                sup.insert(0, prices1[i-1])

            supports1.append(sup[0] if len(sup) > 0 else NaN)

        supports[stock] = supports1
    return supports
#----------------------------------------------------------------

print 'fun1', timeit('calc_supports1(prices)', \
            setup='from __main__ import calc_supports1, prices',number = 1)
print 'fun2', timeit('calc_supports2(prices)', \
            setup='from __main__ import calc_supports2, prices',number = 1)
```

How can I speed up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is multiple performance problems in this code.

- Python loops are slow (with the default interpreter CPython). It is probably better to use things like Cython or Numba for such kind of computation.
- Pandas manual indexing is slow. It is better here to use Python lists here and even avoid indexing in hot sections of the code.
- Inserting/Removing elements in the beginning of a list may be much slower. The Python documentation advise to add elements at the end to implement a stack.

Here is the corrected code:

```py
def calc_supports3(prices):
    supports = DataFrame().reindex_like(prices)
    for stock in prices:
        prices1 = list(prices[stock])
        sup = [min(prices1[0],prices1[1])]
        supports1 = [NaN, sup[-1]]

        # Sliding window
        prices1_im2 = NaN
        prices1_im1 = prices1[0]
        prices1_im0 = prices1[1]

        for i in xrange(2,len(prices1)):
            prices1_im2, prices1_im1, prices1_im0 = prices1_im1, prices1_im0, prices1[i]

            while len(sup) > 0 and prices1_im0 < sup[-1]:
                sup.pop()

            if prices1_im1<prices1_im0 and prices1_im1<prices1_im2:
                sup.append(prices1_im1)

            supports1.append(sup[-1] if len(sup) > 0 else NaN)

        supports[stock] = supports1
    return supports
```

Here are performance results on your small dataset on my machine:

```
fun1 0.006461 s
fun2 0.000901 s
fun3 0.000648 s (40% faster than fun2)
```

Here are performance results on a randomly-generated dataset with 50 000 lines:

```
fun1 3.916947 s
fun2 2.064891 s
fun3 0.034465 s (60 times faster than fun2)
```

Comment: Just using list (prices1 = list(prices[stock])) speeds up 75 times on my machine compared to fun2, in large dataframe. Why didn't I think of that? In total your corrections speed up 86 times. Great lesson, thank you.